# Library for create ethereum wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, wallets, cpp-ethereum, ethereumjs

I want to create an ethereum wallet that is erc20 compatible on my client side.

It should allow user to enter his own password and generate private key, recovery phrases and utc file.

I try to research online and discover `web3js` and it seems that it cannot fulfill my requirement. Any reliable library ?

I am expecting something like `Ethereum.generateWallet(randomKey, password)` and it will do everything. It should be best done in client side using javascript.

Comment: I know a couple of libraries that can be used as base to develop a wallet [eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) and [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet).